# Data query to keep the common data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

Table 1 : It the final table contains all data .
ID and IDS are composite key

```html
ID      IDS    name
1       PL35    Bumper
151111  PL35    Bumper
151111  PL36    Bumper
1516    PL35    TUMI
151511  PL36    Limo
151521  PL35    Superb
151521  PL36    Superb
```

table 2 : Its a pre final table which will upcoming data with incomplete information

```html
ID      IDS    name
15100   PL35    NULL
1516    PL35    NULL
151521  PL36    NULL
151511  PL36    NULL
```

EXPECTED RESULT  : Some IDs (ID+IDS)  are in Table 1 and some are in Table 2 . I need to compare the data of  table 1 and table 2 .
The rule is
Keep the common data with Table 1 information
Keep the new row with (id+IDS) which  is in table 2 but not in table 1

for eg;

1. (15100 + PL35)  is in table 2 but not in table 1 then it will remain
2. (1516 + PL35) is common in both then the row from table 1 will
   remain.
3. ( 151511 + PL36) is also common hence will remain .
4. The data (ID +IDs) which is not in table 2 but in table 1 is not needed.

```html
    ID      IDS    name
    15100   PL35    NULL
    1516    PL35    TUMI 
    151511  PL36    Superb
```

SO far I am only think about this

```
select * from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: if new id+IDS is in table 2 and not in table 1 then it will also be shown here

Comment: I cannot make any sense of that. Your description reads like you want a full join with a lot of `coalesce()`s, the desired result looks partly like a left join and partly not matching anything... Please revise and elaborate.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for the valuable time. I have edited the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INTERSECT, named after the equivalent set operation.

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   IDS
FROM
  table1
INTERSECT
SELECT 
   ID,
   IDS
FROM
   table2
```

**EDIT**
In answer to your question, you can wrap this in a CTE and then join back onto table1.

```
WITH common AS
(
  SELECT 
       ID,
       IDS
    FROM
      table1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT 
       ID,
       IDS
    FROM
       table2
)
SELECT  
   c.*, 
   t.Name 
FROM common c
INNER JOIN
    table1 t
 ON c.ID = t.ID
 AND c.IDS = t.IDS
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked partially . if I add the name column I get nothing in result. Is theirs anyway way that what ever the results I am getting should have the name column included ?

Comment: Have a look at the edit.

Comment: Can I out this in a view ? I am getting this error  `Msg 4506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MOLD_VIEW, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'id' in view or function 'MOLD_VIEW' is specified more than once.`

Comment: This condition is not meeting `(15100 + PL35) is in table 2 but not in table 1 then it will remain` . I have a row which is in table 2 not in table 1 is not coming in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use FULL OUTER JOIN, and put a WHERE condition WHERE t1.id NOT NULL and t2.id NOT NULL.

Comment: ` t1.id NOT NULL and t2.id NOT NULL` are always like this. These field are "NOt NULL"

Comment: @Yogus No a full join would have nulls for the sides which don't match